# Add out of stock product to quote

Tags: adminhtml, quote

I'm trying to add a product to a quote in admin (programmatically), the model of the quote is `sales/quote`, as seen in sales_order_place.

Problem is the quote will not accept products which are out of stock, even though I've called `Mage::helper('catalog/product')->setSkipSaleableCheck(true);`?

I want to have the ability to add products to the quote regardless of their stock status.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went the route of resolving things by:

```
$stock_item = $product->getStockItem();
$stock_item->setIsInStock(true);
//then add product to quote
```

This way the quote sees the product as in stock, but because you don't call up a `save();` function, changes aren't pushed to the DB. Strange though that the setSkipSaleableCheck function doesn't seem to help resolve things.